# Rotating an image after being added in a PDF using Reportlab

Tags: image, pdf, rotation, pdf-generation, reportlab

I'm trying to create a PDF document with an image that will be rotated.
I can successfully create the PDF document, add the image and save it, but as soon as I try rotating it, I'm having many issues.

One thing I'm trying to understand is where is the axe for the rotation, is it at 0,0 (bottom left for PDF) or somewhere else?

Here's my current running code:

```
output = BytesIO()
# create a new PDF with Reportlab
c = canvas.Canvas(output)

c.saveState()
c.translate(X?, Y?) # TODO find this !
c.rotate(45)

c.drawImage('path/to/image.png', position_left, position_top, width=img_width, height=img_height, mask='auto')
c.restoreState()
c.save()
```

(Since PDF documents (0,0) point is at bottom right, I have `position_left` and `position_top` that refers to the top left point of the document, where I want to place the image).

My issue here is that I don't know how what values to put on `c.translate(X?, Y?)` to make the image rotate on its center axis, i.e. stays at the same position on the document, but rotate on itself from its center point.

Is using `c.translate(X?, Y?)` would work or do I need to use advanced mechanisms to rotate "just" the image on the PDF document?

Comment: *"PDF documents (0,0) point is at bottom right"* - sure about that? In general it's arbitrary but very common is bottom *left*.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, it's bottom left, my bad! I'll fix this!

Comment: So you want to place an image at `x,y`  with a center `x+w/2, y+h/2` and then rotate the same by some degrees? Is that assumption correct. Also see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848988/a-simple-method-for-rotate-images-in-reportlab

Comment: @TarunLalwani This helped me find the solution! Thank you!!

Comment: Should I post that as a answer or you have used any modifications?

Comment: yes, go ahead :)

Comment: Per the answer, a duplicate of this: [A simple method for rotating images in reportlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848988/a-simple-method-for-rotating-images-in-reportlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the technique mentioned in below SO Thread

[A simple method for rotate images in reportlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848988/a-simple-method-for-rotate-images-in-reportlab)

```
from reportlab.platypus.flowables import Image

class RotatedImage(Image):

    def wrap(self,availWidth,availHeight):
        h, w = Image.wrap(self,availHeight,availWidth)
        return w, h
    def draw(self):
        self.canv.rotate(90)
        Image.draw(self)

I = RotatedImage('../images/somelogo.gif')
```